# Error Message URL Parameters Causing Duplicate Content

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I've made an application using PHP and i seem to be having a few issues in Google (Possibly others too) with duplicate content, or similar pages being indexed at least.

I'm using the URL parameter 'error' to notify users or warnings and errors etc, but despite notifying Google of the 'URL parameters' having no effect on content in Webmaster tools, both the below pages are being indexed, and I'm getting a high number of index status 'Not Selected' pages in WMT as a result.

`http://www.myurl.com/a-topic-on-something?error=some+error
http://www.myurl.com/a-topic-on-something`

(Both the above pages are the same apart from a small error message to notify the user of their mistake)

How do web applications normally show error messages without causing duplicate content issues and the parameter version being indexed. I could use POST instead of GET, but it seems a little silly doing that jut to show a simple error message.

It might not be a huge issue, but i want to get rid of any duplicate issues if i can.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the error message as a session variable:

```
SESSION['error'] = 'some error';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply collect any errors in a array and then return them to the page and display them.

```
$errors = array();

$errors[]= " this is an error";

if($errors)
 {
   return $errors
 }
```

Comment: The errors occur on a different page though, then the user is redirected back to a page with the error message showing, so it needs to be passed through a URL... unless I'm misunderstanding something in your answer.